# Proof - compactness implies sequentially compactness

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, compactness

> Let's assume that $X$ is a metric space and $M$ a compact set of $X$. Show that $M$ is sequentially compact.

**My approach:**

Let be $\epsilon>0$ arbitrarily chosen, then we define an open cover by $\mathcal{F}:=\bigcup\limits_{x\in M}U_{\epsilon}(x)$ where $U_{\epsilon}:=\{y\in M\mid \Vert x-y\Vert<\epsilon\}$. Then there exists a finite subcover $\mathcal{F}_0:=\bigcup\limits_{i=0}^nU_{\epsilon}(x_i)$. Now we chose an arbitrary sequence $(a_n)\in M$ and know that at at least one of the finite many $U_{\epsilon}(x_i)$ contains infinitely many members of $(a_n)$. WLOG we assume that $U_{\epsilon}(x_0)$ contains infinitely many members of $(a_n)$. Then, we create an index of a subsequence $(a_{n_j})$ of $(a_n)$ by the following procedure:
$$
n_1:=\min\{i\in\mathbb{N}\mid a_i\in U_{\epsilon}(x_0)\}\\
n_2:=\min\{i\in\mathbb{N}\mid a_i\in U_{\epsilon}(x_0)\setminus \{a_{n_1}\}\}\\
n_3:=\min\{i\in\mathbb{N}\mid a_i\in U_{\epsilon}(x_0)\setminus \{a_{n_1},a_{n_2}\}\}\\
\cdots
$$
As $U_{\epsilon}(x_0)$ contains infinitely many members of $(a_n)$ this procedure doesn't stop and by construction the resulting subsequence converges to $x_0$. $(a_n)$ was arbitrarily chosen so every sequence in a compact set contains a convergent subsequence.

---

Is this correct?

Comment: Nice effort! I would use $d(x,y)\lt \epsilon$ in place of $\| x-y\| \lt \epsilon$, for generality. IMO, your proof is not correct. You need to show $\forall \delta \gt 0$, $\exists N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $d(x_{n_j}, x_0)\lt \delta$ , $\forall j\geq N$. You have carefully constructed subsequence $(a_{n_j})$ of $(a_n)$. There maybe some $\epsilon^{\prime} \gt 0$ such that $\epsilon^{\prime} \lt d(x_{n_j},x_0) \lt \epsilon, \forall j\in \Bbb{N}$. You can also use well ordered property to show existence of $\min$. Though it is obvious.

Comment: You start "Let $\epsilon>0$ be chosen."  Now your goose is cooked.  You have committed to a particular $\epsilon$ (e.g., $\epsilon=\frac12$) for the rest of your proof.  Thus your proof produces a subsequence inside that particular $U_{\frac12}(x_0)$ neighborhood and need not converge.   Your sequence depends on the particular $\epsilon$ you used.

Comment: So you need a hint. Suppose that there is a sequence $\{x_n\}$ that has no limit point. That means for every $x∈X$ there must be an open set $O_x$ that contains $x$ and  that contains only finitely many points of the sequence $\{x_n\}$. Etc.